# Поиск максимальных подстрок

Tags: алгоритм, строки

Дана строка s, состоящая из строчных латинских букв. Необходимо для каждой позиции i в строке s найти наибольшую по длине подстроку x, начинающуюся в позиции i в s, которая также ранее встречается в строке s. Т.е. нужно найти наибольшую длину Li, для которой найдется позиция `i' < i`, такая что `s[i'..i'+Li-1] = s[i..i+Li-1]`. Например для строки ababaab ответ будет `{0,0,3,2,1,2,1}`. Асимптотика работы должна быть меньше `O(|s|^2)`. У меня есть предположение, что задача решается через суффиксный массив, но все, что я придумал, работает как минимум за `O(|s|^2)`. Нужно меньше

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая идея: оптимизировать метод суффиксного массива для этого случая.
Заметьте, что длины *L<sub>i</sub>* в результирующем массиве идут по убыванию. Если на *i*-той итерации была обнаружена общая подстрока длиной *L<sub>i</sub> = n*, то на следующей итерации подстрока будет начинаться со второго символа первой подстроки и её длина будет *L<sub>i+1</sub> = (n - 1)*, а потом - *L<sub>i+2</sub> = (n - 2)* и тд. до *L<sub>n-1</sub> = 1*. Это можно использовать и, обнаружив на *k*-той итерации подстроку длиной *n*, запомнить её позицию *pos*. В следующей итерации поиск подстроки можно начинать с *(pos + 1)*.

Это красиво звучит, но не совсем верно. Я решил начать объяснение с простого и намеренно опустил один важный случай. Рассмотрим следующую строку

```
ababaabababaab 

{0,0,3,2,1,5,4,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}
```

Обратите внимание, что внезапно вместо предполагаемой длины *L<sub>7</sub> = 3* мы получили *L<sub>7</sub> = 7*! Подстрока `ababaab` содержится в этой строке целиком, если искать с нулевого символа, а не со второго.

В связи с этим немного перефразирую наблюдение, озвученное выше:

> Если на *i*-той итерации была обнаружена общая подстрока длиной *L<sub>i</sub> = n*, то на следующей итерации подстрока будет начинаться со второго символа первой подстроки и её длина будет **не менее** *L<sub>i+1</sub> = (n - 1)*

И вот сейчас я точно не знаю, что делать...  Если придумаю надёжный способ обрабатывать такие случаи, вернусь к этому вопросу.